# Looking for a limited shuffle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle, array-algorithms

I have a shuffling problem.  There is lots of pages and discussions about shuffling a array of values completely, like a stack of cards.

What I need is a shuffle that will uniformly displace the array elements at most N places away from its starting position.

That is If N is 2  then element I will be shuffled at most to a position from I-2 to I+2  (within the bounds of the array).

This has proven to be tricky with some simple solutions resulting in a directional bias to the element movement, or by a non-uniform amount.

Comment: I'm curious where you came up with this, or what made you think you needed this behavior.  It's left me and my coworkers stumped, so thanks for posing it!

Comment: It is actually a graphics problem.  Look at the command "ppmspread", or the ImageMagick convert option "-spread".  In both cases the source implies that it swaps pixels, and thus preserves all the pixels in the original image, just displaced.  However... That is not the case, both image operators actually loose information with pixels being duplicated and lost.

I wanted to get this 'naive' approach fixed, but just simply swapping pixels as you work through the image results in some pixels becoming 'double swapped'.  A search for a solution has not been fruitful.

Comment: Note that if N is the same size (or larger than) the actual array, the shuffle should essentially devolve to a full shuffle of the array.  Though in normal  usage N should be quite small relative to the array length. Typically between 1 and 5.

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in `ppmspread`/`spread`?  Have you looked at the source code for these operations?  Links to the documentation you're looking at would be helpful, so we're sure we're looking at the same things.

Comment: The original source code of those image processing says they are shuffling, and ppmspread even goes through the trouble of swapping both elements,  But they only modify a destination image, leaving the source image as is. That means as it works its way through elements that were 'swapped' ahead of the current processing point, get over written by a later 'swap.  You can see it loosing pixel data if you process a gradient image, where every pixel is unique and in sequence before hand.
[link](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/contrib/graphics/src/netpbm-9.25/ppm/ppmspread.c)

Comment: I'm obviously not answering the questions, but if the initial array is sorted, you could shuffle it completely, and then use a Shell Sort that stops at a gap of `2N` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this is tricky! First, we need to establish some more rules, to ensure we don't create artificially non-random results:

- Elements can be left in the position they started in.  This is a necessary part of any fair shuffle, and also ensures our shuffle will work for N=0.
- When N is larger than an element's distance from the start or end of the array, it's allowed to be moved to the other side.  We could tweak the algorithm to forbid this, but it would violate the "uniformly" requirement - elements near either end would be more likely to stay put than elements near the middle.

Now we can actually solve the problem.

1. Generate an array of random value in the range `i + [-N, N]` where `i` is the current index in the array.  Normalize values outside the array bounds (e.g. `-1` should become `length-1` and `length` should become `0`).
2. Look for pairs of duplicate values (collisions) in the array, and recompute them.  You have a few options:

   - Recompute both values until they don't collide with each other, they could both still collide with other values.
   - Recompute just one until it doesn't collide with the other, the first value could still collide, but the second *should* now be unique, which might mean fewer calls to the RNG.
   - Identify the set of available indices for each collision (e.g. in `[3, 1, 1, 0]` index `2` is available), pick a random value from that set, and set one of the array values to selected result.  This avoids needing to loop until the collision is resolved, but is more complex to code and risks running into a case where the set is empty.
3. However you address individual collisions, repeat the process until every value in the array is unique.
4. Now move each element in the original array to the index specified in the array we generated.

I'm not sure how to best implement #2, I'd suggest you benchmark it.  If you don't want to take the time to benchmark, I'd go with the first option.  The others are optimizations that *might* be faster, but might actually end up being slower.

This solution has an unbounded runtime in theory, but should terminate reasonably quickly in practice.  Again, benchmark and test it before using it anywhere critical.

Comment: In summary:  create a separate array of randomised indexes, within the +/- N range of the current index. Then look for resolve duplicate indexes.  That resolution process could be difficult, if not impossible, from that position.

Comment: The third option (compute the set of available indices) would run in bounded time, though I'm not convinced it's actually better than the unbounded options in the general case.  Like I said, you'd need to benchmark it.  If a resolution proves impossible, it may be the case that your problem does not have a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I have come up with though how 'naive' it is I am not certain. Especially at edges, the far edge especially.

1. create a array of flags (boolean) N long (representing elements that have been swapped)
2. For At each index check if it has already been swapped (according first element in flags array) if so, move on to next (see below)
3. rotate the flags array, deleting the first element (representing this
   element), and add a new 'not swapped' element to end.  ASIDE: This
   maybe done using a modulus array lookup, to avoid having to actually
   move array contents, especially for large N
4. Loop...

   - pick a number from 0 to N (or less than N, if N plus current
       index is larger that array being shuffled.
   - If 0, element swaps with itself, move to next.
   - Otherwise if that element marked as swapped, Loop and try again.
     Note there is always 2 elements in flags array that can be picks, itself
     and the last element (unless close to end of array being shuffled)
5. Swap current element with selected unswapped element, mark the selected element as swapped in the flags array. Loop to next element

Comment: I'll attempt to rephrase, just so I can understand.  You're suggesting looping over each element in turn, identifying a valid position to place it, and then trying again if that position has already been filled.  Is that right?  If I'm not mistaken, this will not be uniform, because elements closer to the end of the list will have fewer available positions than those at the head.

Comment: Only if they had not been swapped already.  At the end the array marking elements that have not been shuffled would be getting smaller.

Hmmm if you think about it with a value of N equal to or larger than the size of the array, it would devolve down to a Fisher-Yates shuffle, but without the chance of elements being shuffled again if they have previously been shuffled.  To me that should be uniform.